# How to write a test case for password and Confirm password PasswordMatching validation Directive

Tags: angular, user-interface, jasmine, karma-runner

I am working on writing Unit test cases for the Password Mismatch Validator. How can I write a test spec for below method?

I tried searching the internet but was not able to set the value for the form control

```js
export class PasswordMatchingValidation {

  constructor() {}

  static MatchPassword(AC: FormControl) {

    const password = AC.get('password').value; // to get value in input tag
    const confirmPassword = AC.get('confirmPassword').value; // to get value in 

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {

      AC.get('confirmPassword').setErrors({
        MatchPassword: true
      });

    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  /**
   * validate if the passwords are matching
   * @param ctrl Takes Form Control
   */
  validate(ctrl: FormControl) {
    return PasswordMatchingValidation.MatchPassword(ctrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: The short answer is no. Angular has guidance on testing here: https://angular.io/guide/testing. If you have something that doesn't work, give a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first you should initialize a new `FormControl` with some dummy data and the call the `PasswordMatchingValidation.MatchPassword` with the control you previously made as an argument and assert the outcome.

```
const control = new FormControl({password: 'whatever'});
describe('PasswordMatchingValidation', () => {
  it('should validate two identical passwords', () => {
    const validation = PasswordMatchingValidation.MatchPassword(control);
    expect(validation).toEqual({ MatchPassword: true });
  });
});
```

Make your `FormControl` like it's supposed to be and of course assert the opposite case as well